# loading a trained facerecognizer model

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to load a saved model, but i'm not doing it right. Would appreciate some help. Below is bytefish his code, edited here and there. The couts are added for debug purposes.

The loading of the model i got from :
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UjWoIFHcr58C&pg=PT446&lpg=PT446&dq=how+do+i+use+model-%3Eload+facerecognizer&source=bl&ots=S9i2zxkw6w&sig=LoQ6IdwdH0C6_07h1sCSFXJs8Jg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAwZuGy9fMAhXmCcAKHVf_Boo4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

But i made it into a vector so i could compare it with images more easily.

The full code is on http://answers.opencv.org/question/94241/loading-a-model-not-working-crashing/ as i can't seem to paste the full code here it seems. Hope that is ok. Also i find answers.opencv.org quite low volume.

Comment: Please don't paste links to other sites. If the code is too much to paste, your example isn't minimal.

Comment: Sorry i thought it would be helpful to see the entire code. I will try and extract the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

All face recognition models in OpenCV are derived from the abstract base class cv::FaceRecognizer and need to implement the two pure virtual methods cv::FaceRecognizer::save and cv::FaceRecognizer::load for persisting a model:

```
class FaceRecognizer : public Algorithm
{
public:

// Some other functions here:
// ...

// Serializes this object to a given cv::FileStorage.
virtual void save(FileStorage& fs) const = 0;

// Deserializes this object from a given cv::FileStorage.
virtual void load(const FileStorage& fs) = 0;
}
```

[refer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3446/how-is-facerecognizer-model-stored/)